# PDO Left Join :Show record once instead of twice

Tags: join, pdo

I'm trying to link two tables with left join and then show the player's first name and his chosen character(s), but when I echo the result I get the player's first name record twice:

Player's first name: Jelle

Player's first name: Jelle

Player's Character's first name: Gandalf

Player's Character's first name: Aragorn

**When I actually want this:**

Player's first name: Jelle

Player's Character's first name: Gandalf

Player's Character's first name: Aragorn

I understand that I get the record twice if the player has two characters but how do I show the player's first name once and all the rest of the corresponding characters?

```
This is my code:



   try{
    $statement = $connection->prepare('
    SELECT *
        FROM TBL_Player
    LEFT JOIN TBL_Character
        ON TBL_Player.ID = TBL_Character.Player_ID
        WHERE TBL_Player.ID = 1;                
    ');
    $statement->execute();

    while (($Player = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) !== false){
        echo "Player's first name: ".$Player->FirstName. "</br>";
        echo "Player's Character's first name: ".$Player->CharacterFirstName. "</br>";

    }

} 

catch (PDOException $e){
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a counter, and only output the Player name on the first time through the loop:

```
$i=0;
while (($Player = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) !== false){
  if( $i == 0 ){
    echo "Player's first name: ".$Player->FirstName. "</br>";
  }
  echo "Player's Character's first name: ".$Player->CharacterFirstName. "</br>";
  $i++;
}
```

Or if you have multiple players you can keep track with an array

```
$aryTracker = array();
while (($Player = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) !== false){
  if( !in_array($Player->Id, $aryTracker) ){
    echo "Player's first name: ".$Player->FirstName. "</br>";
    $aryTracker[] = $Player->Id;     
 }
  echo "Player's Character's first name: ".$Player->CharacterFirstName. "</br>";

}
```